# Is there a better way to count substring occurrences within a string than char* and a loop?

Tags: c++, string, substring

I have this line:

```
const char *S1 = "AaA BbB CcC DdD AaA";
```

I think that this creates a pointer `*S1`, which is located a constant char type value and has the `AaA BbB CcC DdD AaA` value in it. Is that right?

If so, how can I read each character of this constant value and recognize how many times `AaA` occurs?

I was thinking of creating a loop that will copy each letter to a different cell and then 3 enclosed `if` statements, of which the first could check for `A`, the second for `a` and so one. And if those 3 are true I will increment a counter like so `i++`. Is that correct?

I think it's too complicated and it can be done with less code.

Comment: If `S1 = AaAaAaA`, then how many times did you find `AaA`? two or three times?

Answer (score 1):

Your fundamental approach is sound. However, it’s complex and doesn’t scale: what if you wanted to search for a word with more than three letters? Four `if`s? Five `if`s? Six …? Clearly that won’t do.

Instead, use two loops: one to go over the string you search *in* (the “haystack” or “reference”) and one over the string you search *for* (“needle” or “pattern”).

But luckily you don’t even have to do that, because C++ gives you the tools to search for the occurrence of one string in another, the `find` function:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string const reference = "AaA BbB CcC DdD AaA";
    std::string const pattern = "AaA";

    std::string::size_type previous = 0;
    int occurrences = 0;
    for (;;) {
        auto position = reference.find(pattern, previous);
        if (position == std::string::npos)
            break;
        previous = position + 1;
        ++occurrences;
    }

    std::cout << occurrences << " occurrences of " << pattern << '\n';
}
```

You can look up the individual types and functions in the [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/). For instance, you can find [the `std::string::find` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) there, which does the actual searching for us.

Note that this will find nested patterns: the reference “AaAaA” will contain two occurrences of “AaA”. If this isn’t what you want, change the line where the `previous` position is reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve what you want is using `strstr(str1, str2)` function, [which returns a pointer to the first occurrence of str2 in str1, or a null pointer if str2 is not part of str1.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/)

```
int count_sequence(const char *S1, const char *sequence) {
    int times, sequence_len;
    const char *ptr;

    times = 0;
    sequence_len = strlen(sequence);
    ptr = strstr(S1, sequence); //Search for the first sequence
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        times++;
        ptr = strstr(ptr + sequence_len, sequence); //search from the last position
    }
    return times;
}
```

Comment: Please no `strstr` in C++. There are better ways.

Comment: @Demetris, #include <string.h>

Comment: @Claudix Oh, man that's worse than `strstr`. If you have to do this, at least go for `#include <cstring>`.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ way:

- using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for string management, it provide a lot benefit, memory management, iterators, some algorithms like `find`.
- using [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method of `std::string` to search for the index of `s1` where `s2` begin, if `s2` is not present in `s1` (a dummy value **std::string::npos** is returned).

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s1("AaAaAaA");
    //std::string s1("AaA BbB CcC DdD AaA");
    std::string s2("AaA");

    int times = 0;
    size_t index = s1.find(s2, index);
    while (index != std::string::npos) {
        times++;
        index = s1.find(s2, index + 1);
    }

    std::cout << "Found '" << s2 << "' in '" << s1 << "' " 
              << times << " times" << std::endl;
}
```